# How to get data from Wordpress post :(

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, content-management-system

I have  a post under link : "http://loreleiheckmann.com/wordpress/wordpress/2020/03/13/name-surname/" 
I've tried to get a JSON file via: http://loreleiheckmann.com/wordpress/wordpress/wp-json/wp/name-surname?_embed&per_page=4 unfortunately it doesn't work :( what do I do wrong?:(

Comment: Have you checked the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#arguments) yet? If you want to get a single post via the REST API using its slug you should be using the `slug` parameter with your request.

Comment: I've just created Custom field - trainers and I try to get a content from there. Post was a wrong place :(

Comment: that's the answer :) I sort it out: http://loreleiheckmann.com/wordpress/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/trainers

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to sepcify the Wordpress API Version

This will work

```
http://loreleiheckmann.com/wordpress/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
```

Comment: sorry. I just came back from maternity leave XD I sort it out by my own : http://loreleiheckmann.com/wordpress/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/trainers